# R programming: How to count different values’ frequency among all columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I’ve been struggling to code a frequency dataframe from another that has 5 possible values c(0,2,3,4,5) for each row, in which values c(2,3,4,5) appear only once and “0” is not unique, this obtained from a survey of preferences where “5” is the most preferred option, down to “2” that is the less preferred (of the available columns); “0” is given to not-chosen columns, so it repeats.

```
df(c(Op1,0,5,0,0,...),

c(Op2,2,4,0,0,...),

c(Op3,0,0,5,5,...),

c(Op4,5,0,0,2,...),

c(Op5,0,0,4,0,...),

c(Op6,4,3,3,4,...),

c(Op7,3,2,2,3,...))
```

Each row is a person, and this values were numbered for clustering this information, but what I would like to do is to count how many “5”’s, ..., “0”’s were given in total for this options, something like:

```
///////5 / 4 / 3 / 2 / 0

Op1 / 21 / 12 / 9 / 5 / 0

Op2 / 0 / 3 / 25 / 10 / 9

Op3...

Op4...
```

...

The top being a header, and the numbers below the frequency of each option in total (every person)

I’ve tried using table() and count() but count() counts per option individually, and table() doesn’t count values if they don’t appear, for example, if Option2 didn’t have any 5-rated preference, it won’t show it as “0” and it creates different tables of each option, I want a fully integrated dataframe as shown above.

Please and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with the sample data you provided, if I understand your request correctly:

Data:

```
dd<-data.frame(c("Op1",0,5,0,0),
c("Op2",2,4,0,0),
c("Op3",0,0,5,5),
c("Op4",5,0,0,2),
c("Op5",0,0,4,0),
c("Op6",4,3,3,4),
c("Op7",3,2,2,3),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(dd)<-dd[1,]
dd<-dd[-1,]
```

Now the actual solution:

```
library(dplyr)
do.call(bind_rows, sapply(dd,table))
```

What this does is apply `table` to every column individually, and then use `dplyr`'s `bind_rows` to link everything up together. `bind_rows`, unlike `rbind`, keeps columns of different names separate. Here's what it looks like:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
    `0`   `5`   `2`   `4`   `3`
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     3     1    NA    NA    NA
2     2    NA     1     1    NA
3     2     2    NA    NA    NA
4     2     1     1    NA    NA
5     3    NA    NA     1    NA
6    NA    NA    NA     2     2
7    NA    NA     2    NA     2
```

And to tidy it up a bit:

```
ddd<-do.call(bind_rows, sapply(dd,table))
ddd[is.na(ddd)]<-0
ddd[,order(names(ddd))]
# A tibble: 7 x 5
    `0`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     0     0     0     1
2     2     1     0     1     0
3     2     0     0     0     2
4     2     1     0     0     1
5     3     0     0     1     0
6     0     0     2     2     0
7     0     2     2     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you reshape your dataframe into a longer format, group by OP ids and values, make the count using `count` and reshape our dataframe into a wider format to have the count of each values per OP.

NB: For missing values, if you want to have them display as 0 count, you need to pass `values_fill` arguments, otherwise, you will have some `NA`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = "OP",values_to = "values") %>%
  group_by(OP,values, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = values, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) 

# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   OP [3]
  OP      `0`   `1`   `2`   `4`   `5`   `3`
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Op1      10     1     1     1     1     0
2 Op2      11     0     1     0     1     1
3 Op3      12     1     0     0     0     1
```

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
df <- data.frame(Op1 = c(rep(0,10),sample(1:5,4)),
                   Op2 = c(rep(0,11),sample(1:5,3)),
                   Op3 = c(rep(0,12),sample(1:5,2)))
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, 0:5))))`

Comment: Nice ;). I did not know about this use of `table` in a `lapply` function. You should make an answer of it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` package to transform the data into long format and then use the function `dcast` to calculate the frequency:

```
dd <- data.frame(c("Op1",0,5,0,0), c("Op2",2,4,0,0), c("Op3",0,0,5,5), c("Op4",5,0,0,2), c("Op5",0,0,4,0), c("Op6",4,3,3,4), c("Op7",3,2,2,3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(dd) <- dd[1, ]
dd <- dd[-1, ]

library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dd), measure = patterns("Op"), variable = "op"
     )[, dcast(.SD, op ~ value)]

#        op     0     2     3     4     5
# 1:    Op1     3     0     0     0     1
# 2:    Op2     2     1     0     1     0
# 3:    Op3     2     0     0     0     2
# 4:    Op4     2     1     0     0     1
# 5:    Op5     3     0     0     1     0
# 6:    Op6     0     0     2     2     0
# 7:    Op7     0     2     2     0     0
```